# Will this Trigonometric give the following answer?

Tags: trigonometry

If $n$ is an integer, can $$\cos[(2n-1)\pi/2]-\cos[(2n-1)\pi/4]$$

be equal to $\;\;\cos[(2n-1)\pi/4],\;\;?$

I have tried the formula for $\cos A-\cos B$ but that would give result in $sine$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$\cos \left((2n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos \left(\pi n-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0.$$

Comment: ok so that means the answer must come with a negative sign. Thanks

Comment: The equation is actually and part of another question where n is taken as an integer.

Comment: @CalvinLin and Aman: I took the liberty to add the fact that $n$ is an integer to the post itself, given Aman's comment immediately above.